# emacs: why does what-cursor-position return less than the expected value?

Tags: emacs

Suppose I have a source file that is 18218 bytes.

I open the file in emacs, then do:

```
 M-x end-of-buffer
 M-x what-cursor-position
```

Why does the cursor position return 17612 bytes?

I think it's because of CRLF translation, or collapsing CRLF into one character.

How can I get emacs to report the accurate, untranslated character position?

Comment: What you're asking for isn't a *character* position, it's a byte position. byte != character. Even before unicode came out (19 years ago) this was a false equivalence because of the CR/LF convention on DOS and some other platforms.

Comment: Ah, very true.   What I am interested in, in this case, is the byte position.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The behavior you describe is mentioned in the [manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Text-and-Binary.html).  No way of getting the "true" position is mentioned, which leads me to believe that you're out of luck.

You can, however, open the file without any conversions applied like this: <kbd>C-x RET c no-conversion RET C-x C-f filename</kbd>.  Then all of the character positions should match up correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect opening the file using `find-file-literally` will stop Emacs from auto-detecting line endings and convert CR LF to "line break".

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the non-interactive function (point) is what you need. I haven't noticed such discrepancies about it, but then again - I haven't paid any particular attention to such details...